# Pattern not working - Locked out of phone

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, pattern-lock

I have an Android 6 device.

Since this morning when I woke up, my pattern is no longer working and the wifi mobile hotspot was turned off during the night (it was on when I went to sleep).

After a few tries and waiting 30 secs, it lets me access the phone thru the backup pin, but if i try to change the pattern (settings -> security -> security lock) or to reset the settings, it asks for the pattern again, which of course no longer works.

Any ideas what to do about this situation? Would prefer not to lose all my apps / settings / data.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you'll **NEED** to root your device if you haven't done that (You didn't specify what device you have, so Google "(device's model number here) root")

But **READ** this post: https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-disadvantages-of-rooting-Android-devices/answer/Ashwin-Afhen before rooting your Android device

Now, download **THIS** terminal emulator **AFTER** rooting your Android device: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm, open it up and type these commands:

```
su
rm -f /data/system/locksettings.db*
rm -f /data/system/gesture.key
```

And now, **REBOOT** your Android device and you **SHOULD** see no pattern lock or a pattern lock that can be unlocked with **ANY** pattern (and then, unlock your device and set a new pattern)

And unroot your Android device

That's all I can say for now

Comment: No easier solution?

Comment: @Click Upvote Yes

Answer (score 0):

From [this](http://www.addictivetips.com/android/how-to-bypass-disable-pattern-unlock-on-android-via-adb-commands/) addictivetips.com post:

1. Enable USB Debugging (find it somewhere under settings in
   developer or development or about phone submenues or by tapping 7
   times on Build number according to make and model of your phone)
2. Download and install ADB tools (there is [this guide](http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/what-is-adb-and-how-to-install-it-android/) referenced)
3. Connect phone to PC using USB cable
4. Run the followin in a command prompt (if 2nd one fails just continue):

   `adb shell
   mv /data/system/gesture.key /data/system/gestur.oldkey
   cd /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases
   sqlite3 settings.db
   update system set value=0 where name='lock_pattern_autolock'
   update system set value=0 where name='lockscreen.lockedoutpermanently'
   .quit`

Comment: how can he enable usb debugging if he is locked out ?

Comment: He told he could enter the phone by a sort of fallback PIN code, but he is not able to manage the pattern setting. Of course I think he could also do a factory-reset but it is not what he desires currently.